# Joomla "JPath check" error pops up randomly

Tags: php, joomla, relative-path

I am working with Joomla 3.1.1, and I have SEF and URL rewrite turned on and everything works great.

My problem started when I tried to access a directory of my site such as

```
www.mywebsite.com/myfolder
```

I kept getting a error due to the URL rewrites. So I solved that with putting in a .htaccess file just for that directory and I was finally able to access it however now when I try to run code php I keep getting this error and it comes and goes with time passing, seems to be 24hours as I am getting it now on my third day of dev.

```
JPath::check Use of relative paths not permitted
```

If joomla is blocking access to directories that is great however is there a way to create like a whitelist of directories that I can allow to be accessed

Also don't know if it makes a difference or not but when I run www.mywebsite.com/myfolder
I am calling a php file which has a

```
include_once  'another.php';
```

The content of another.php file is

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 ) or die('restricted');
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php' ); 
$app =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
```

Also if I open and re-save the content of another.php file the error goes away only to pop up again the next day.

Comment: Try the latest version of Joomla. 3.1.1. is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

If you open up `/libraries/joomla/filesystem/path.php`

You will find

```
public static function check($path, $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
{
    if (strpos($path, '..') !== false)
    {
        // Don't translate
        throw new Exception('JPath::check Use of relative paths not permitted', 20);
    }

    $path = self::clean($path);
    if ((JPATH_ROOT != '') && strpos($path, self::clean(JPATH_ROOT)) !== 0)
    {
        throw new Exception('JPath::check Snooping out of bounds @ ' . $path, 20);
    }

    return $path;
}
```

The first if statement is where it kept falling in, because my jpath has a /../ in the path. To resolve it I have commented out the throw new Exception line.